# Setting column so only 1 of 2 values are allowed

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a column so it can only have 1 out of 2 different values. Example, right now the type is varchar(8), but I want it so that only valid values accepted are the words "Bitcoin" or "Paypal". I know I can do this with PHP, but is it possible with MySQL?

Comment: You can use `ENUM`.

Comment: For simplicity and efficiency's sake, you can use a boolean to represent one or another, since there is only 2 options.

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 while true (pun not intended :p), that could potentially lead to some HUGE scaling issues later in the life of this code base. Even though Marc may not be planning on ever scaling this to other payment processors, if this program ever takes off he will definitely want to ability to add different payment types than just the 2, and should probably plan for scalability (within reason)

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 even more efficient is to use a `char(0) null` type, and store '' for PayPal or null for Bitcoin.  That way, the data actually only takes up one bit.  But don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace  with your table name and  with your cloumn name

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
    CHANGE COLUMN <column name> ENUM('Bitcoin','Paypal') NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You need to specify the new column name, even if it isn't changing. (In other words, `<column name>` needs to appear twice after `CHANGE COLUMN`.) Alternatively, use `MODIFY` instead of `CHANGE COLUMN`.

Comment: Perfect, this was actually what I was looking for. @Gordon Linoff explained it, but you showed me how it was done. I did the change in phpMyAdmin and it worked out great.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you have three or four choices.

- You can use an enumerated type.  This defines the type and the allowed values.
- You can use a foreign key relationship to a reference table that only contains these two values.
- You can use a trigger to enforce the values.

In other databases, you also have the option of using a check constraint.  MySQL does not actually implement those.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go for a completely normalized approach, I would do something like this:

```
Customer
id auto_increment pk
name VARCHAR(255)
payment_type_id INT(10)
```

Then have a separate table:

```
PaymentTypes
id auto_increment pk
name VARCHAR(255)
```

If you're using InnoDB, you'd put a foreign key on the column payment_type.

To query for the payment type, simply join the tables:

```
SELECT c.Name, pt.Name as 'Payment Type'
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN PaymentTypes pt ON pt.id = c.payment_type_id
```

This is one of the better options as it allows for later additions of payment types later on.

Comment: This is what I would do and avoid enum like the plague